# Nodejs Jest mocking is not working in multiple describe block in a single file, it works in first describe block only

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, jest-mock-axios

I am using jest for unit testing in my node express application,please excuse , because i am new to all this

in my abc.test.js

```
const s3Helper = require('../../../../../lib/s3_helper');

beforeEach(async () => {
  s3Helper.uploadBufferToS3 = jest.fn(() => true);
});
describe('test1', () => {
 it('test1', async () => {

   expect(s3Helper.uploadBufferToS3)
      .toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
});

describe('test2', () => {
 it('test2', async () => {

   expect(s3Helper.uploadBufferToS3)
      .toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
});
```

so when i run this test file in test1 it returns that test is passed, however in test2 it returns expected >=1 returned 0.
since i am mocking it beforeEach i expect it should return 1 for each describe block

Comment: why to use beforeEach? just set a mocked function after require

Comment: tried , still doesnt work

Comment: if you want use `.toHaveBeenCalled()` you should call that